# Bash: write on file terminal output changing color of string

Tags: string, bash, colors

I'm writing a script to submit jobs using HTCondor and at the same time I would like to write in a .txt file the output message shown on terminal coloring the ClusterID number.

On the code side I have:

```
[some code...]
    condor_jobid=${type_dir}/jobs_id.txt
    echo -e "\033[0;32m---------------START---------------\033[0m" >> $condor_jobid
    echo $name >> $condor_jobid
[other code...]

    submit $jobName 2>&1 | tee -a $condor_jobid
    echo -e "\033[0;31m----------------END----------------\033[0m" >> $condor_jobid
```

The output from "submit" command is:

```
Submitting job(s).
1 job(s) submitted to cluster 323.
```

What I see on my file is:

```
---------------START--------------- [in green]
My_job_name
Submitting job(s).
1 job(s) submitted to cluster 323.
----------------END---------------- [in red]
```

but I would like to have in my file only the last string of the output and the ClusterID in blue:

```
---------------START--------------- [in green]
My_job_name
1 job(s) submitted to cluster *323*.
----------------END---------------- [in red]
```

Can I do it in bash?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
submit $jobName 2>&1 | tee -a $condor_jobid
```

to

```
submit $jobName 2>&1 | grep -v Submit | tee -a $condor_jobid
```